# Can't serialize tasks with gulp.series()

Tags: gulp

Only the first function passed to `gulp.series()` does fire, the rest just don't. Below is my (simplified) `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  ...
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
  ...
});

gulp.task('images', function() {
  ...
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1/protection/',
  })
})

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browserSync', 'js', 'sass', function() {
  gulp.watch('../assets/styles/**/*.scss',['sass']);
  gulp.watch('../**/**/*.php', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('../assets/scripts/*.js', ['js']);
  gulp.watch('../*.html', browserSync.reload);
}));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function(done) {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1/protection/',
  })
  done();
})
```

And all other tasks either:

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
  reurn gulp.src()...
});
```

or

```
gulp.task('images', function(done) {
  ...
  done();
});
```

---

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browserSync', 'js', 'sass', function() {
  gulp.watch('../assets/styles/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
  gulp.watch('../**/**/*.php', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('../assets/scripts/*.js', gulp.series('js'));
  gulp.watch('../*.html', browserSync.reload);
}));
```

---

```
gulp.watch('../assets/styles/**/*.scss', 'sass');
```

might work as well since you are only calling one function/task.  I usually just future-proof it a bit with the `gulp.series('sass')` way of doing it it.

Gulp v4 expects a function (hence your error message) as the second parameter to `gulp.watch` instead of the gulp v3 array of tasks old parameter.

Comment: Getting "Error: watching ../assets/styles/**/*.scss: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)"